# angularjs ngRepeat Sometimes I can't scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, macos, angularjs, google-chrome

I have an angular site, everything's pretty async. Dom elements render after page load and things just pop in. Sometimes, around 10%, of times when I load the page after it finishes loading scrolling down is impossible. On Chrome OSX no scroll bar pops up when I use the mousewheel or the spacebar. It just appears stuck. Note that the page is not frozen, interacting with most elements work just fine, just the scrolling is broken. Only the up down keys work. Once I click on the up down keys it becomes fine to scroll with mousewheel and spacebar.

What causes this problem and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a combination of CSS an html. Do you have any sample code that we could see?

Comment: I get the same issue sometimes, not sure whats causing it but its annoying. Refreshing the works, or page up / down but using the mouse to scroll does not work. Chrome 35 in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Please check other browsers!

I can only confirm this issue in Chrome...

see [google help forum: Anyone having trouble with Google Chrome unable to scroll, focus, etc?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/kA_XpWIhJT8%5B1-25-false%5D)

Comment: I see this issue as well with Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit) on Yosemite.  I can't reproduce the issue with Safari or Firefox.